# iterating over JSON in javascript to put into select options

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-select

I keep having issues iterating over some JSON to put in select options
(btw, ignore the actual values for "label", those are garbage atm).

Here is an example that my php is passing into this:

```
[{"value":"1","label":"04-22-12"},{"value":"4","label":"04\/04\/12"}]
```

I am currently trying this loop:
*note, dateSelect is defined somewhere else

```
for (res in JSON.parse(request.responseText)) {
    var date = document.createElement("option");
    date.value = res.value;
    date.text = res.label;
    dateSelect.add(date, null);
}
```

However, it is adding "undefined" into my options...
How do I get it so each value and corresponding label is put in there correctly?

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(request)`?

Comment: No need to use markup to format your code, simply select it and click in the `{}` icon (or type `<pre></pre>` for code blocks and `<code></code>` or the ` character for inline code).

Comment: or better yet, use the `\`` symbol for inline code ;)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find a nice way to put that in a comment. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an Array, so don't `for-in`.

In your code, `res` is the property name *(the index of the Array in this case)* in the form of a `string`, so the properties you're looking for aren't going to be defined on the string.

Do it like this...

```
for (var i = 0, parsed = JSON.parse(request.responseText); i < parsed.length; i++) {
    var res = parsed[i];
    var date = document.createElement("option");
    date.value = res.value;
    date.text = res.label;
    dateSelect.add(date, null);
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. This just helped me solve a hugeee problem I was having (bigger than this little problem I posted).